# Website Broken on Activating Child Theme!

Tags: child-theme

My website (at http://japanaddicts.org) breaks down in a rudimentary pro-HTML form when I try to activate the child theme.

My parent theme is Codilight. Just explain to me why is this happening. I am not looking for Codilight-specific premium support, but a reason that any knowledgeable person will know.

I have prepared my child theme with nothing but this:

```
/*  
    Theme Name:   Codilight Child
    Theme URI:    
    Description:  A modified and more specific version of Codilight.
    Author:       Prince
    Author URI:   http://japanaddicts.org/
    Template:     codilight
    Version:      1.0.0
    Tags:         pink, lesser social buttons
    Text Domain:  
*/
@import url("../codilight/style.css");
```

I've uploaded it to a new directory wp-content/themes/codilight-child. When I activate it and open my website, it opens in a broken format (not fully HTML neither fully Codilight style). I had to revert back to the original/parent Codilight.

I've read the guide at WordPress Codex and it doesn't help. Here's a screenshot of how my website looks under the child theme:

[image: Screenshot of the website under the child theme]

Comment: Please provide details to which parent theme are you using, and add the complete header for your child style.css, that is everything from the top to just after the @import part

Comment: @PieterGoosen Done

Comment: Codilight is a paid-for 3rd party theme. You'll probably have a hard time getting support for it on WPSE - does your fee not include support with the developer?

Answer (score 1):

Enable [WP_debug](http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) by editing your wp-config.php in your WordPress root files

Look for:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
```

Change to:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

Post any error messages in your top post, this will help us identify where the issue could be.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your import statement is trying to import the CSS directory of the parent theme, rather than the style.css file.

Take a quick look at the [Codex article on Child Themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

You'll want to change your import statement to:

```
@import url("../codilight/style.css");
```

Comment: I found that the style.css file was in /codilight all right, and so I made the change and replaced the older file with the newer one. But still it's the same.

Here's a screenshot of how does it **still** look:
http://i1278.photobucket.com/albums/y515/abhimanyu0003/Screenshotfrom2014-05-28113916_zps4948f599.png

Comment: Your site is currently displaying properly, with the Codilight Daughter theme properly importing the parent stylesheet http://d.pr/i/zgkw

Answer (score 0):

If you examine your pages source code CAREFULLY, check the URL’s of your stylesheets and scripts. Click on them to see if you get 404 error pages on some of them or of it opens the file.

If you are getting error pages then these files are likely referencing your child theme directory now instead of your parent theme directory where the files actually reside.

The way around this is to copy the entire folder structure of the parent theme across into the child theme.

Alternatively you can replace all incorrect instances below in the actual parent theme with the correct functions listed below:

`get_template_directory_uri();` or `get_stylesheet_directory_uri();`

with:

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri();` or `get_template_directory_uri();`

Problem with this is that unless the developer of the theme updates this on his side, every time you update the theme this will be overridden, which defeats the whole purpose of a child theme in the first place!

I wrote a brief article on this if you want to take a look. [View article](http://mattroyal.co.za/2013/11/wordpress-child-theme-applying-but-not-working-properly/)

Comment: Wait, there's too much and I'm new and so I'm terrified...